# Second WiFi card stopped all WiFi

Tags: 13.04, lubuntu, dell, broadcom, ralink

I have Broadcom BCM4313 internal Wireless. I have also Ralink RT2870/3070 USB Wireless adapter.

This is normal connections menu.

[image]

I also plugged Ralink USB Wireless in my computer.

This is after plugged USB Wireless in. and now Broadcom and Ralink doesnt work.

[image]

```
osman@inspiron-n4030:~$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: phy2: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
osman@inspiron-n4030:~$
```

i tried `sudo rfkill unblock all` but didnt worked. can someone help me?

Comment: In my experience, often one wireless driver interferes with another. If you unplug the usb card, and reboot, does it work? If so, you will have to blacklist your BCM4313 and re-try the usb.

Comment: i tried. but didnt work.BCM43xx is already added in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf if is it correct directory for blacklist.but they are working together on liveUSB. another way?

Answer (score 1):

The usb device will overide the internal device when it is plugged in. 
`rfkill` says it is hardblocked that usually means the physical switch is off, see if you have a switch or it may be a key combination like <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> for example.

Comment: i tried. switch is on. Broadcom is working well if dont plug second 
wifi in. Broadcom and Ralink blocked when i plugged Ralink USB in.
(sorry for bad ENG)